# Using GLSurfaceView class with android xml layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I want to make use of the android xml layouts. I have put a glSurfaceView in a frame layout to use in conjunction with a linear layout like so...

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceviewclass"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/gamecontrolslayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="5"
          android:background="@drawable/backdrop"> 
//some layout stuff

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

I then call my layout like so

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceviewclass);
```

in onCreate();

How can I call my glSurfaceView so that I can make use of the xml layouts like this and also reference my own GLSurfaceView class (below is code that references my own GLSurfaceView class)...

```
glSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
```

Is there anyway of combining these two?  I want to do this cos I've got a load of stuff going on in my glSurfaceView class like file loading and touch events. And only I've just thought about implementing this new layout

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just reference your own class (with full packagename) in the xml, the same way you reference android.opengl.GLSurfaceView. Make sure that your subclass implements the proper constructor, and passes the context & attributes to the parent:

```
public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
   super(context, attrs);
```

Then you can fetch it using findViewById:

```
MySurfaceView glSurfaceView = 
             (MySurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceviewclass);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: My Surface View doesn't have an attribute set should that matter?

Comment: Just implementend the above says that it has trouble inflating class. Error comes from the xml file

Comment: `public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {` and the constructor `public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
  super(context);`

Comment: But now any calls I make to my surface view (ie: `glSurfaceView.requestRender`) have stopped working =(

Comment: NullPointerException (sorry forgot to specify)

Comment: I seem to have fixed that last thing but I'm confused as to why my original life cycle seems to have gone out of the window.

Comment: Any idea why glSurfaceView.onResume would throw a nullPointer in my SurfaceView has been created and (I can only assume that my renderer has been set) No evidence of a surface being created though maybe thats the problem

Comment: Weird Its all working now. Turns out you do all you said except you need to fetch the glSurfaceView with `glSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);` and then set the xml file as the content view How annoying. could you update you answer to fit please.

Answer (score 2):

If everything corect, like you write in the xml-layout, the full Path to the Glsurfaceview-class : (and classname)

it works only if the class, GLSurfaceView, written in a own File.
in this file for shure, the construktors need to be written correctly.

i read about ,1 constructor for xml-refer, and one for comunication between classes.
constructor for xml-refer, and one for comunication between classes, can be found, if written correcly, inside GLSurfaceView
.
GLSurfaceView, is where you set the Renderer,
set it in the the xml constructor, must be the only way, it works fine. (shown in anwer 1)

xml-constructor:

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs);
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
renderer = new Renderer(context); 
setRenderer(renderer);

If you some of this peoples,
who cant get SurfaceView work, in xml-layout ore, who buy this book from Apress - Beginning 3D- Game-Development.
dont be angry ore hurt yourself.
At page 44-45 it be written, in one file.
Write GLSurfaceView,  like in my answer, in own file.
Renderer is own file, where: 
onSurfaceCreated, 
onSurfaceChanged, 
onDrawFrame..can be found
And The MainActivity

Comment: if you realy learn gl es for android, i would buy the print from the book"Beginning And...3D" - Robert Chin, to it beside you desk , see the new bosten.